# Cannot load a second vaadin app's second UI in a first vaadin app UI using iframe and navigator

Tags: iframe, vaadin, navigator

I am trying to load a second Vaadin app second UI in my first vaain app UI

navigator which I returned in my second vaadin app

iframe I returned in my first vaadin app

while calling second app second UI ex: `http://localhost:8080/#!SecondUI` in Iframe(BrowserFrame) it always loading second app FirstUI only

This is how I wrote:

```
//(given in APP1 UI)
{
    browser = new BrowserFrame("VAADIN APP2 ", new ExternalResource("http://192.168.5.109:8080/#!SecondView"));
    browser.setWidth("100%");
    browser.setHeight("400px");     
    addComponent(browser);
    setSizeFull();



//(this is how I initialize navigator in second app UI)

    navigator = new Navigator(UI.getCurrent(), form);

    navigator.addView(FirtsView.VIEW, new Firstview());
    navigator.addView(SecondView.VIEW, new SecondView());

    navigator.navigateTo(FirtsView);
```

Please help me! And how can I call directly to the second UI of second app?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing, if you could provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) it would be easier to understand your issue and help you out.

Comment: Thanks any way I got the answer, follow sscce on next qsn ownwards